# Linux isn't allowing to create enough sockets but not many sockets are being used

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

My C++ application creates 64-128 UDP sockets.

It creates sockets using this code:

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
assert(sock != -1, strerror(errno));

const u_int yes = 1;
int result = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));
printf("sock=%i result=%i errno=%i\n", sock, result, errno);
if(result != 0)
{
    FATAL(strerror(errno));
}
```

However, at the moment it's only creating 2 sockets because `setsockopt()` returns -1 on the third request:

```
sock=1023 result=-1 errno=0
```

(`stderror(errno)` just says `success`)

I'm puzzled because when I run `ss` it doesn't look like many sockets are in use:

```
ss -s
Total: 238
TCP:   85 (estab 16, closed 40, orphaned 0, timewait 37)

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
RAW       2         1         1        
UDP       24        17        7        
TCP       45        30        15       
INET      71        48        23       
FRAG      0         0         0
```

My understanding is you may have 1023 sockets. So the above implies I should be able to create 64-128?

How/what is the problem here?

Comment: Is the code you pasted the exact code that produced the output you show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no limit on number of open *sockets*, but there is more general limit on number of opened *file descriptors*. The fact that it fails on fd=1023 suggests that this limit was truly hit, since on a typical Linux:

1. file descriptors are assigned consecutive numbers starting with 0
2. default limit (`ulimit -n`) is 1024 opened file descriptors

You can check the number of opened file descriptors with `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd | wc -l`. I suspect that you have many opened (regular) files.